# If $n\geq3$, show that if $\alpha \in S_n$ commutes with every $\beta \in S_n$, then $\alpha = (1)$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I've been stuck in this problem for a while and I don't really know how to start.
I was thinking in something like this:

Suppose that $\alpha \beta=\beta \alpha$ and $\alpha\neq{(1)}$, then $\alpha, \beta$ are disjoint permutations. Suppose that exists $i,j$ such that $\alpha(i)=j$ then $\beta(i)=i$, and $\alpha(\beta(i))=j$ but $\beta(\alpha(i))=\beta(j)=j$.

I don't know what I'm missing or if I'm doing something that doesn't make sense. Any hint on how should I start would be really appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that's the identity element in $S_n$

Comment: If you could show the "then $\alpha, \beta$ are disjoint permutations," then you'd be done.  Unfortunately it's not a true implication.

Comment: Is there a permutation $\alpha$ other than the identity such that $\alpha(\alpha(i))=i$ for any $i$ ?

Comment: Instead, let $\alpha \neq (1)$ be arbitrary and define a transposition $\beta$ dependent on $\alpha$ such that they don't commute.  You may find it beneficial to consider cases on the form of $\alpha$ depending on whether it has a fixed point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the permutation $\alpha\ne(1)$. So for some $i$ we have $\alpha(i)=j$ with $j\ne i$.

We now consider two cases.

Case 1. $\alpha(j)=i$. Take $k\ne i$ and $k\ne j$. If we apply $(ik)$ followed by $\alpha$, then $j$ goes to $i$. But if we apply $\alpha$ followed by $(ik)$, then $j$ goes to $k$. So the transposition $(ik)$ does not commute with $\alpha$.

Case 2. $\alpha(j)=k$ where $k\ne i$ and $k\ne j$. If we apply $(jk)$ followed by $\alpha$, then $i$ goes to $j$. But if we apply $\alpha$ followed by $(jk)$, then $i$ goes to $k$. So $(jk)$ does not commute with $\alpha$.